# Create custom site template based on existing "From Microsoft" site templates in Modern SharePoint Online

Tags: site-template, site-design, site-script

When I go to **Apply a site template** --> **From Microsoft** section, I can see there are many site templates. From these many site templates, I can select any site template like "Brand Central" and apply to my site.

What is want here is, I have to create my custom site templates based on all existing site templates. Disable all the existing templates in section **From Microsoft** and add my custom site templates to **From your organization** section.

My problem is, I am not able to extract existing site script/site template and create my own.

Answer (score 0):

You can used PnP to create a template.  Have a look at the PNP documentation for it [here](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPSiteTemplate.html?q=Get-PnPSiteTemplate).

```
$templateSiteUrl = "https://esslabs.sharepoint.com/sites/Project-Template"
$templateFileName = "c:/temp/Project-template-01.xml"
Connect-PnPOnline $templateSiteUrl -Interactive
Get-PnPSiteTemplate -configuration -Out $templateFileName -IncludeAllPages
```

However that doesnt copy over content and I dont know how to add it to Organisational templates.  Let me know if you find out!